# Test isolation broken with multiple databases in Django. How to fix it?

Tags: python, django, testing, transactions

> Django’s TestCase class wraps each test in a transaction and rolls
>   back that transaction after each test, in order to provide test
>   isolation.

Apparently, however, only operations in the `default` database are within the scope of the transaction. I have a multiple database setup with a router that directs ORM calls on some models to a second database. This means that in the following example, `test2` fails:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test1(self):
        # Let's say Foo model ORM calls are routed to a different DB
        foo = Foo.objects.create(...)
        assert foo.is_ok()

    def test2(self):
        assert not Foo.objects.exists()
```

The most immediate solution to this problem would be to override the `tearDown` method in `MyTestCase` and manually make sure to delete all `Foo` objects. But this is a bit annoying because it's sort of a hack and database sequences (e.g. autoincrement columns) won't be reset for example, only after the test suite is done and the database is destroyed.

Is there a way to properly fix this, making sure all database operations are by default made inside a transaction and rolled back at the end of each test?

[UPDATE]

Here's my router:

```
class FooRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.app_label == 'foo':
            return 'foo_db'

        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.app_label == 'foo':
            return 'foo_db'

        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):

        if app_label == 'foo':
            return db == 'foo_db'

        return None
```

Comment: Hum, I don't know, I wouldn't think so. It's a pretty basic router. But anyway, I added the code, hope it helps.

Comment: `test2` fails. Sorry I wasn't very explicit. Just updated the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 11):

As *multi_db* is deprecated, you can now achieve test with multiple database with the new attribute **databases**

```
class YourTestCase(TestCase):
   databases = '__all__'

   def test_something(self):
       pass
```

Comment: `multi_db` is deprecated from Django 2.2 version

Answer (score 1):

In case you are **not using DB Router**, you can try to add `multi_db = True` to TestCase to **call flush for all databases**

```
class YourTestCase(TestCase):
   multi_db = True

   def test_something(self):
       pass
```

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#multi-database-support)